# cakephp views caching doesn't work

Tags: php, caching, cakephp

I'm trying to get working views caching just as is described [cache chapter](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1376/Cache) on book.
I created dir /tmp/views, and chmod 777 on it. Relevant helper is being autoloaded.

I use default settings in core.php :

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
Configure::write('Cache.check', true);
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
```

And in my controllers (i also tried with arrays):

```
var $cacheAction = true;
```

I'm using newest 1.3 version. Any ideas ?

Comment: uhm, so what's the problem? how do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The cache directory is `APP/tmp/cache/views` - unless you just made a typo.

Also I (personally) haven't seen `var $cacheAction = true`, so perhaps try:

`var $cacheAction = "1 hour";`

or

```
var $cacheAction = array(
                      'view/' => 5000
                   )
```

for a specific action, 
and see if you get better luck.